# MARS MIPS bubble sort

Tags: string, mips

everyone. I'm just completing my homework but there's something wrong with my assembly code. Teacher asked me to create a 10-integer array then sort descendingly and print it to screen. I chose bubble sort and actually it works. However, when I print the array after being sorted to the screen, there're no space `" "` between them. I initialize `space: .asciiz " "` as the code below and also used `v0,4` to print but I still dont know why it doesn't work. Can anybody help me? Thanks very much!

This is my code:

```
.data
    array: .word 10
    sentence: .asciiz "Please enter a 10-integer array: "
    space: .asciiz " "
.text
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,sentence
    syscall

    li $s0,0
    li $t0,10
    la $t1,array
    
    for_input:                     ##### This is the loop used for input the array
    beq $s0,$t0,exit_for_input
        li $v0,5
        syscall
        sw $v0,0($t1)
    addi $t1,$t1,4  
    addi $s0,$s0,1  
    j for_input
    exit_for_input:
    
    #bubble sort
    li $s0,0
    li $t1,9
    li $t2,10
    li $t3,0
    for_outter:
    beq $s0,$t1,exit_outter
    addi $s1,$s0,1
    addi $t4,$t3,4
        for_inner:
        beq $s1,$t2,exit_inner
            la $t0,array
            add $t0,$t0,$t3
            lw $t5,0($t0)       #arr[i]
            
            la $t0,array
            add $t0,$t0,$t4 
            lw $t6,0($t0)       #arr[j]
            
            slt $t7,$t5,$t6
            li $t8,0
            
            beq $t7,$t8,exitif  #swap
                sw $t5,0($t0)
                la $t0,array
                add $t0,$t0,$t3
                sw $t6,0($t0)
            exitif:
        addi $t4,$t4,4
        addi $s1,$s1,1
        j for_inner
        exit_inner:
    
    addi $t3,$t3,4
    addi $s0,$s0,1
    j for_outter
    exit_outter:
    
    li $s0,0
    li $t0,10
    la $t1,array
    
    for_output:
    beq $s0,$t0,exit_output
        lw $t2,0($t1)
        move $a0,$t2
        li $v0,1
        syscall     #print arr[i]
    
        li $v0,4
        la $a0,space
        syscall     #print space " "           #### The problem is here
    addi $s0,$s0,1      #increase i
    addi $t1,$t1,4
    j for_output
    exit_output:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

If I enter `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. The result must be `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` but it's in fact `10987654321`

Comment: You didn't reserve enough space for the array, so the code overwrites your strings to print later.

Comment: Change `array: .word 10` with `array: .space 40`

Comment: Ah I saw it :) i tended to use .word 0:10 but i forgot. Thanks!!!